# conjure-up juju and nested containers

Tags: juju, lxd, conjure-up

We have (almost) deployed Openstack NovaLXD with conjure-up on a single machine. In this setup, conjure-up uses juju and lxd, and creates nested lxc containers. All of them comes up with IP addresses, but all the nested containers fails to complete the setup.

I would like to attach to the console of the nested containers, to troubleshoot network and see logs. For the first level of containers, I can add a user with the "*lxc exec*" command, like "*lxc exec juju-e688f9-0 passwd ubuntu*", and then attach to it. When I try to create a user in a nested container, I try "*lxc exec juju-e688f9-0-lxd-1 passwd ubuntu*", but that gives me "Error:not found". I have tried to attach to the console of the first level container, to attach to the nested container from there, but lxd and juju is not available inside the lxc container.

How can I attach to the nested lxc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a user, I found I could just use "lxc shell" to access a container as root. From there, I could use "lxc shell" again to reach the nested container.